# Error when running Java file through Intellij terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA, when I run a java file in the terminal or run a jar artifact, I get this error:

[image]

I have an up to date jdk and runtime enviroment installed on my computer, and I only have one runtime environment installed. Also, I do not have an issue with the actual compilation of the program, just the
"$java Program" command.

Comment: If you are using any lib. it was compiled with newer version of JDK then the one you r using. Try changing "Language Level" to match the version given in error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear: You compiled the Java source with an newer Java version than your are using to execute it.

So your assumption that you have only one Java version installed cannot be correct. Are you aware that the IDE itself comes with a Java runtime?

Next time please post text as text, not a link to an image.